# Embedding finite lattices into the lattice of partitions of a finite set

Tags: order-theory, lattice-theory

For any set $X$ we denote by $\text{Part}(X)$ the set of all partitions of $X$, ordered by the refinement ordering. It is well known that this is a complete lattice for all sets $X$.

Let $L$ be a finite lattice. Is there a finite set such that there is an injective lattice homomorphism $\varphi:L\to\text{Part}(S)$ for some finite set $S$?

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461875/can-we-extend-every-finite-lattice-is-a-sublattice-of-partitions-of-a-finite-se

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is apparently a fairly hard theorem of [Pudlak and Tuma](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02482893) (or at least I assume it is hard, because it seems to have been an open problem for decades before they finally proved it in 1980).

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/201547/what-is-the-smallest-partition-lattice-partm-containing-the-lattice-pn-of-su

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [Wehrung and Semenova](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/226425360_Sublattices_of_Lattices_of_Convex_Subsets_of_Vector_Spaces), they mention "... the result of Ph. M. Whitman [19] published in 1946 that every lattice embeds into the partition lattice of a set." Here reference [19] is

- Ph. M. Whitman, Lattices, equivalence relations, and subgroups, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 52 (1946), 507–522.

Comment: Whitman's result does not guarantee that $S$ is finite, which makes the problem much easier.

Comment: I realize. I'll leave my answer in case it's still useful.